# What form should the parameters for this (user defined) function be in?

Tags: r, calculus, stochastic

I am currently taking a module on stochastic finance for which (despite R not being a prerequisite) I am required to write/modify some code in R. I am currently really struggling to get a valid output from the following code, which we have been given to work with:

```
bmsim=function(nsim,ntime) {
  wn=matrix(rnorm(nsim*ntime),nrow=nsim,ncol=ntime)/sqrt(ntime)
  bm=matrix(0, nrow=nsim,ncol=ntime+1)
  for(i in 1:nsim) bm[i,]=cumsum(c(0,wn[i,]))
  bm
}


stoch.int=function(fun1=fun.null,fun2=fun.null,w=bm,lh=T,sigma=1, nu=1, alpha=1) {
  environment(fun1)=environment()
  environment(fun2)=environment()
  nsim=nrow(w)
  ntime=ncol(w)-1
  jj=0
  if(lh==F) jj=1
  si=rep(0,nsim)
  for(j in 1:ntime) {
    si=si+sigma*fun1(w[,j+jj])*(w[,j+1]-w[,j]) + nu*fun2(w[,j+jj])/ntime
  }
  si
}
```

Having run this code and defined `bm = bmsim(20,20)` in the console, I am struggling to get an output from the function `stoch.int`. The reason for this (I believe) is because I am not providing the parameters for this function in the correct form.

Firstly, since the parameters `fun1` and `fun2` should be functions I am unsure of how to express these values. What variable is it expecting me to use? Should these parameters be given within quotes or not?

Can anyone please help me to understand what kind of parameters would give an output for this function?

I suspect, though I have yet to make it work, that the parameters should be given in a form such as

```
stoch.int(expression(sqrt(1 - x^2)), 'x', expression(sqrt(1 + x^2 + x^3)), 'x')
```

**NOTE:** I apologise if this was not the right place to post this question. The R website (https://r-dir.com/community/forums.html) recommends this as a forum for questions regarding R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the function to run by using this format:

```
stoch.int(function(x) {sqrt(1 - x^2)}, function(x) { sqrt(1 + x^2 + x^3) })
```

It does produce warnings and strange results, but this is how to specify the functions.